# QGIS How to match the CRS for a 0,0 imported CSV file and match it with PWG file?

Tags: qgis

I have downloaded a png file 19200, 19200 pixels with a PGW world file that matches the png file to the real world coordinates.

I am developing an object detection algorithm to take this png file and export a bounding boxes on a csv file for the detected objects: e.g: building: 7279.0, 12082.0, 7285.0, 12084.0.

The only problem that the object detection does not care about the pgw file thus it only generates the bounding boxes related to the png file not the PGW file.

to view the results: I am using qgis, import the png file, then qgis reads the pgw file and display the image on its correct location on the map. But when I input the csv file with the bounding boxes it get displayed in the 0,0 to 19200, 19200 location instead of the real world coordinate system and there is no way to map these two after they get imported unless I delete the PGW file and convert the 0,0 to 19200,19200 coordinates to 0,0 to 19200,-19200 bu that means I can not view the map inside the world background.

Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Any body have any thoughts on this?